# Why is the access to a private field not forbidden?

Tags: java

For my study in the university I'm forced to do some ugly java basics, like working without encapsulation, main method in the same class etc. (I do not want to open a discussion on a java styleguide, I just want to clarify, that I would not write something like this outside of the university)

I've stumbled across a behaviour that I can't explain to my self:

```
public class Person {
  // fields
  private int age;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person foo1 = new Person();
    foo1.age = 40;
    System.out.println(foo1.age);
  }
}
```

Why does this piece of code compile and run without error? How is it possible that I can access the private field? Strange behaviour due to having the main Method in the same class?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because the static method `main` is a member of class `Person` and can thus access any private fields or methods in `Person`.

What are you worried about? That someone will write a class and then be able to access those methods from their own class?

If you're going to be concerned about anything, be concerned that you can access private fields in *any* class using reflection but even that's necessary for a lot of useful things.

Comment: I was just wondering because I expected the private modifier to make the fields only accessable from inside the instance, like I'm used to from C#.

Comment: @citronas - C# behaves exactly the same way - the private modifier applies to the class - not the instance.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx

Comment: @Nate: No it does not. C# does not allow to call a static method from an instance. To call a static method you need the following construct: CLASSNAME.STATICMETHOD().   INSTANCE.STATICMETHOD() will give you a compile error. And static methods do not allow you to access any instance variables, just static ones.

Comment: @citronas: I don't believe that's what Nate is saying. I believe he's saying that C# also allows static methods in a class to access private members of that class if it is given an instance (just like Java).

Answer (score 15):

Yes—in Java, private is *class private* not instance private.

Many other languages use instance private, eg Ruby and Smalltalk.

Comment: Oh, thats new to me. How is the instance private modifier?

Comment: In Ruby all instance variables are private to the instance (not modifier since you get no choice). Same in Smalltalk.

Comment: …and for Java, there is none.

Answer (score 2):

As your main method is in the same class and the instance variable is having private access it is only available to the methods of the same class. there is no access modifier which can restrict the methods of a same class to access its member variable. that is what happening here. if you have your main method in some other class though in the same package it would not have compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You can access private fields from inside their class. That's the point of having them defined per-class.

Answer (score 0):

You can write any other static method in the Person class and access the private variables from that method. *Main* is just a name. Such is life.

Answer (score 0):

Because your method `main(String[] args)` is defined inside the class `Person`. If the method was defined outside the `Person` class you would not have been able to do that.